# grafana dashboard is not working with nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, amazon-eks, kube-prometheus-stack

I have deploy kube-prometheus-stack on my eks cluster. Nginx ingress controller is configured with NLB. I am teminating SSL at NLB. I am trying to expose grafana on subdomain with nginx ingress. When i open subdomain nginx ingress is showing `504 error response`.

I'm using this [helmchart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack)

k8s verison -> 1.22

values.yaml

```
grafana:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    ingressClassName: tf-test
    hosts: 
       - my-dashboard.example.com
    path: /
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, it turns out in the grafana value part, there is an extra path like this

```
      extraPaths:
        - path: "/"
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: ssl-redirect
              port:
                name: use-annotation

that ssl-redirect service does not exist. it works me by just removing it.
```